# How can I create a dynamic list in Excel that ignores some values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following perfectly working Excel formula that allows me to create a dynamic list of "team names". This formula creates an array of cells in column A, starting from row 2, and stopping as soon as an empty cell is found. As soon as I append a new "team name" to this range, it is added to the dynamic list.

```
=Teams!$A$2:INDEX(Teams!$A$2:$A$1001;SUMPRODUCT(--(Teams!$A$2:$A1001<>""))
```

I assigned this formula a name, then use this name as the source for a data validation list.

Now I want to go a step further and keep only lines, based on the value found in the cells of column N. The value in column N can be  (if not set), TRUE or FALSE (booleans). What I want to achieve is to have a dropdown list that contains only "team names" that are "active" (TRUE).

```
Teams!$N$2:$N1001=TRUE
```

Is it possible ? If yes how can I achieve this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need an extra column to achieve this.

In B1, enter `FASLE` (boolean value, not string)
In B2, ctrl+shift+enter

`=IFNA(INDEX(IF($N$2:$N$1001=TRUE,$A$2:$A$1001),MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,IF($N$2:$N$1001=TRUE,$A$2:$A$1001)),0)),"")`

Drag this formula to fill B3:B1001. This will give you the unique list of column A with column N = TRUE.  Apply your formula on `$B$2:$B$1001` instead (i.e. ignore `$B$1`).